# Не обрабатывается callbacks от нажатия inline keyboard

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Такая странная ситуация: есть телеграмм бот, который на продакшене работает, а на тестировочном сервере - нет.

**p.s: токен менял**

Код из `keyboards.py`:

```py
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton
from aiogram.utils.callback_data import CallbackData


callback_anon = CallbackData("confirm", "values")
callbacks = CallbackData("confirm", "values")


async def yes_no():
    button_text = ["Да", "Нет"]
    keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
    keyboard.add(
        InlineKeyboardButton(text=button_text[0], callback_data=callback_anon.new(values="yes")),
        InlineKeyboardButton(text=button_text[1], callback_data=callback_anon.new(values="no"))

    )
    return keyboard


async def submit():
    button_text = ["Отправить нам"]
    keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
    keyboard.add(
        InlineKeyboardButton(text=button_text[0], callback_data=callbacks.new(values="sub"))

    )
    return keyboard
```

Код из `handlers.py`:

```py
from .keyboards import *
from src.config import *
from src.dispatcher import *
from src.BD import *

greeting = \
    """Здравствуй! Мы хотим помочь принять и отпустить прошлое и начать жить настоящим.

Здесь вы можете поделиться своей историей, связанной с влиянием родителей и семьи на выбор, который пришлось совершить, и/или рассказать о психологичной травме, которую пришлось пережить в юном возрасте.

До отправки истории необходимо выбрать, как вы хотите ей поделиться: анонимно или нет.
В случае полной анонимности мы разберем вашу проблему с экспертом, в случае частичной анонимности – пригласим вас для записи подкаста и изменим ваше имя и голос для конфиденциальности.
Если же вы готовы рассказать свою историю публично, то мы сделаем это мягко и деликатно.

С особым трепетом, команда медиапроекта «Мам, пап, дальше я сам»."""




async def collect(msg):
    t = ""
    _id = f"id='{msg.from_user.id}'"
    if select("anonim", _id)[0][0] == "0":
        t += f'О человеке: {select("about", _id)[0][0]}\n'
    t += f"Текст:\n{select('history', _id)[0][0]}"

    update(msg.from_user.id, {"about": t})
    await bot.send_message(msg.from_user.id, f"О Вас собрана такая информация: \n{t}", reply_markup=await submit())


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(message):
    if not len(select("id", f"id={message.from_user.id}")):
        insert({"id": message.from_user.id, "send":0, "click":0})
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, greeting)
        await set_mode(message)
    else:
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Вы уже писали нам")


@dp.message_handler(commands=['about'])
async def about(message):
    if select("send", f"id='{message.from_user.id}'")[0][0]:
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Нельзя")
    else:
        update(message.from_user.id, {"about": " ".join(message.text.split()[1:])})
        await collect(message)


@dp.message_handler(commands=['anonim'])
async def set_mode(msg):
    send = select("send", f"id='{msg.from_user.id}'")[0][0]

    if send is not None:
        if not send:
            await bot.send_message(msg.from_user.id, "Хотите поделиться своей историей анонимно?",
                                   reply_markup=await yes_no())
        else:
            await bot.send_message(msg.from_user.id, "Вы уже писали нам")
    else:
        await bot.send_message(msg.from_user.id, "Нельзя!")



@dp.callback_query_handler(callbacks.filter())
async def send_(call):
    send = select("send", f"id='{call.from_user.id}'")[0][0]

    if not send:
        about_ = select("about", f"id='{call.from_user.id}'")[0][0]
        update(call.from_user.id, {"send": 1})
        for e in admins:
            await bot.send_message(int(e), about_)
        await bot.send_message(call.from_user.id,
                               "Мы получили Вашу историю!\nБлагодарим с особым трепетом и заботой, команда «Мам, пап, дальше я сам»")
        return



@dp.message_handler()
async def history(msg):
    click = select("click", f"id='{msg.from_user.id}'")[0][0]
    writing = select("writing", f"id='{msg.from_user.id}'")[0][0]
    anonim = select("anonim", f"id='{msg.from_user.id}'")[0][0]

    if click and not writing:
        update(msg.from_user.id, {"writing": 1, "history": msg.text})
        await bot.send_message(msg.from_user.id, f"Ваша история:\n{msg.text}")
        if not anonim:
            await bot.send_message(msg.from_user.id,
                                   "Используйте /about, чтобы рассказать о себе: имя, ссылка на ВК/телефон. \n"
                                   "Пример:\n"
                                   "/about Иван +7ХХХХХХХХХХ\n"
                                   "ИЛИ\n/about Иван https://vk.com/***\n")
        else:
            await collect(msg)
    else:
        await bot.send_message(msg.from_user.id, "Я не понимаю Вас!")

@dp.callback_query_handler(callback_anon.filter())
async def choose_anon(call, callback_data: dict):
    chosen = callback_data.get("values")
    click = select("click", f"id={call.from_user.id}")[0][0]

    if chosen == "yes" and not click:
        update(call.from_user.id, {"anonim": 1, "click": 1})
        await bot.send_message(call.from_user.id, "Выбрано: да")
    elif chosen == "no" and not click:
        update(call.from_user.id, {"anonim": 0, "click": 1})
        await bot.send_message(call.from_user.id, "Выбрано: нет")

    await bot.send_message(call.from_user.id, "Напишите свою историю одним сообщением.")
```

На `/start` реагирует, на "выбор анонимости" - нет. Опытным путём выяснилось, что в функцию `choose_anon` никогда не заходит!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первый аргумент CallbackQueryHandler должен быть функцией обратного вызова, а не строкой. Эта функция обратного вызова должна принимать ровно два позиционных аргумента и должна быть функцией сопрограммы ( async def), точно так же, как for CommandHandler(или любой другой обработчик).